# setWidget in validator - $form['widget']->render() doesn't use default

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, widget, validation

I'm creating a 2 widgets in a validator, the purpose is for the user to enter a randomly picked word to confirm an action.

I found that when I run `$form['widget']->render()` in the form template, the default value is not picked up.

I have to use:

```
echo $form['widget']->render(array('value' => $form->getDefault('widget')));
```

Is this a known problem or am I doing something wrong?

While the above patch is workable, my problem is that I have to do the same with the hidden widget, so I have 2 hidden widgets with the same name in my form. I have to trust the latter is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set default value in action?

```
$this->form->setDefault('random_value');
```